# Is water molecule too small to apply tennis racket effect?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, water, molecules

Imagine a water molecule moving in empty space without interference from the surrounding, it has angular momentum and since the 2 hydrogen atoms only share 1 electron each the remaining electrons from the oxygen atom becomes unbonded hence H2O earned its trademark appearance... the mickey mouse head. Anyway I was wondering if tennis racket effect would apply to quantum object? This setup will be on a constant surveillance too.